# Changing "src" attribute of <script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to change the "src" attribute of an existing `<script>` element using Jquery.attr()? It seemed like a simple way to get JSONP to work but I am not able to make this  work for me.

Comment: Why not just add a new script element to the dom?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that a script's `src` can **only be set once**! It is not possible to change the `src` attribute of an existing `<script>` element in the DOM. However, a dynamically created `<script>` element can have its source set (but **exactly once**!)

Comment: i know this is an old answer, but do you have any links to support this. I'm having a similar problem and nothing works so far. any reading materials regarding this would certainly help.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to load a script, you could instead use getScript.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Or, if you want to change the src for another reason, since script tags can't have id's, you could either use an HTML5 compliant `data-id` attribute, or match using the existing src. Then you could just change the src value using [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). But this may not load the script on all browsers.

Comment: *"since script tags can't have id's,"* Sure they can, whatever makes you think otherwise?!

Answer (score 3):

Whilst, yes, this is possible, you don't need to do this manually as jQuery has good built-in support for JSON-P requests. See the documentation for the [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) and [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) methods.

Comment: This is not the question. The question is "can you change the src at all if the script tag is pre-existing?"

Comment: Nice gratitude. Read your question again; it read like someone wanting to do JSON-P but thought they had to do it manually. If you want to do it manually, see Aram's answer.

Comment: Not a matter of not having gratitude - you interpreted the question wrong. The question was not about how to do JSONP in JQ, it was a technical point about changing script src. Your answer was not helpful.