# Javascript comparison between an array value and a string

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, comparison

Consider this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="some2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

    for (i=0;i<scripts.length;i++){

        if(scripts[i].src=="some.js") {
        scripts[i].src = "somechanged.js";
        }
    }


</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"></script>
```

I dont know why the `if` is not working. If you comment with // the if it will work for all readed script src. I try some tricks like `toLowerCase()` and/or `valueOf()`, but none worked.

I change the if to `if(1==1)` and of course it works.

What im doing wrong into the string comparison?

Regards

Comment: print the src values. You will see that the urls look different than you think.

Comment: `src` properties are absolute URL. If you want the attribute in the HTML - try `scripts[i].getAttribute("src") === "some.js"`

Comment: Also changing the src of the script does not work anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007591/changing-src-attribute-of-script

Comment: omg, the src is taking the long path call (localhost/etc/etc) instead the relative url.

Comment: do a `console.log(scripts[i].src)` in your script and see what is displayed in the javascript debugging console.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: How can i check your answer correct from a comment? :)

Comment: @sjkm thanks for suggestion, i see the full path when tried ;)

Comment: Do all of the scripts on the page have a `src`?

Comment: @erm3nda I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added comment as answer on par with your request.

- `src` properties are absolute URL. This is specified in the specification.
- You want the actual *attribute* you set it to, rather than the property the DOM is actually using to get it.
- If you want the attribute in the HTML, you can use `scripts[i].getAttribute("src")` which will return the correct value.

Comment: WORKING. thanks! Laziness don't got prizes :) ... make an answer not a comment.