# change src from script which depend on the browser size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, src

I got a little bit problem for my website

I'm trying to change src attribute from my script based on the browser size which the script is inside of div

here is how the code looks like

```html
<div style="margin: 15px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
<script id="world" type="text/javascript" src="http://localtimes.info/world_clock2.php?&cp1_Hex=ffd700&cp2_Hex=000000&cp3_Hex=000000&fwdt=72&ham=0&hbg=0&hfg=0&sid=0&mon=0&wek=0&wkf=0&sep=0&widget_number=21000&lcid=SNXX0006,USNY0996,UKXX0085,ASXX0112,HKXX0001"></script>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the src from the script which the src itself contain width (fwdt value in the script) of the widget that I want to change based on browser size

I'm trying to solve my problem with the following code

```
    <script>
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  if (w>991) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width: " + w ;
    $('#world').attr('src','http://localtimes.info/world_clock2.php?&cp1_Hex=ffd700&cp2_Hex=000000&cp3_Hex=000000&fwdt=200&ham=0&hbg=0&hfg=0&sid=0&mon=0&wek=0&wkf=0&sep=0&widget_number=21000&lcid=SNXX0006,USNY0996,UKXX0085,ASXX0112,HKXX0001');
  }
  else if (w<991) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width: " + w ;
    $('#world').attr('src','http://localtimes.info/world_clock2.php?&cp1_Hex=ffd700&cp2_Hex=000000&cp3_Hex=000000&fwdt=100&ham=0&hbg=0&hfg=0&sid=0&mon=0&wek=0&wkf=0&sep=0&widget_number=21000&lcid=SNXX0006,USNY0996,UKXX0085,ASXX0112,HKXX0001');
  };
</script>
```

however, my code does not do anything to the script src

what i found from internet was to create the script itself, which using appendChild...but, the appendChild work by using tag name, which in my case my script is child from div...

is there a way to solve it?

NEW

```
    <script>
  var w = window.innerWidth;

  if (w>991) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width " + w;
    $('#asd').append('<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/localtimes.info\/world_clock2.php?&cp1_Hex=ffd700&cp2_Hex=000000&cp3_Hex=000000&fwdt=100&ham=0&hbg=0&hfg=0&sid=0&mon=0&wek=0&wkf=0&sep=0&widget_number=21000&lcid=SNXX0006,USNY0996,UKXX0085,ASXX0112,HKXX0001\"><\/script>');
  }
  else if (w<991) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Width " + w;
    $('#asd').append('<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/localtimes.info\/world_clock2.php?&cp1_Hex=ffd700&cp2_Hex=000000&cp3_Hex=000000&fwdt=200&ham=0&hbg=0&hfg=0&sid=0&mon=0&wek=0&wkf=0&sep=0&widget_number=21000&lcid=SNXX0006,USNY0996,UKXX0085,ASXX0112,HKXX0001\"><\/script>');
  };

</script>
```

I try to use the above code, but it does not work too

It only shows the width number, but the append function does not do anything

"asd" is the id of the div

is there other solustion?

Comment: `appendChild` can also be called for the div, so you can lookup the div and append a script tag to it as a child. But I doubt if it is the right way to go. I'd download the script as-is, and let the script itself configure itself based on the screen resolution. I think it's needlessly complex and generates overhead to download different scripts for different resolutions. Perhaps a little insight in the contents of the script will allow us to suggest in more detail how you can make it work for multiple screen sizes.

Comment: @Budi Wijaya - You don't need to place \ in front of double quotes. You have single quotes around script tag, so it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Setting SRC attribute of script tag can be done only once. You have append new script tag programatically.

See this answer [Changing "src" attribute of <script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007591/changing-src-attribute-of-script)

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```
<div id="container" style="margin: 15px 0px 0px; display: inline-block; text-align: center;">
    <script id="world" type="text/javascript" src="<your src>"></script>
</div>





var w = window.innerWidth;
  $("#demo").html("Width: " + w);
  $("#world").remove();
  if (w > 991) {
      $('#container').append('<script id="world" type="text/javascript" src="<your src>"></script>');
  }
  else if (w < 991) {
      $('#container').append('<script id="world" type="text/javascript" src="<your src>"></script>');
  };
```

Comment: are you sure you added id="container" to div holding script? If yes, please post your code on fiddle, I will check.